# Method to Create Multiple Layouts in Android

Tags: java, android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments

I have been thinking of two ways I can create the layouts for my activities and wonder which is the better way to do it? Optimizing resources and speed up the application.

My activities have a constant menu tab control bar at the bottom of the page. The center will be used to house the contents respective content selected (content has no similarity, all of them uses different layouts)

Method One:

Use one activity and house all fragments required (which contains the contents) and do a .replace to swap fragments whenever needed. (However, do I instantiate all fragments at the onCreate on at xml? Or is creating it on runtime, whenever required more advisable?)

Method Two:

Use multiple activities, each to house only a specific content. Use an intent to send to the appropriate activity when required. This will require the duplicate of the constant menu tab control bar as stated before.

Can someone please advise me the better method and how should I implement it would be more appropriate?

Comment: I'd prefer method one, as it's probably faster if youre going to switch between those fragments, also this is one of the example use-cases (i think) they are ment for. You can set your fragments  to retain their state, which will keep them at exactly the position you've left them. Also, to create/destroy activities all the time seems way more performance-heavy than creating or simply replacing existing fragments, which you can store in simple variables/references.

Comment: @damain Thanks for your reply! I had the same thoughts too. Just not too sure about where to instantiate all of them so that it doesn't affect the performance. Would it be best to instantiate all of them at xml level or at the oncreate of an activity housing them? Or instantiate on runtime when they are needed? (the user may experience a little delay, will they? upon clicking an button to open the fragment.)

Comment: Depends on how big your fragments are, I'd say. For my app, I'm creating them "on runtime" (if == null), and keep them, and it's perfectly smooth.